# Different text bounding for NSAttributedString by platforms

Tags: ios, text

I used this code to measure size of an `NSAttributedString`.

```
static NSStringDrawingOptions const OPTS    =   NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                            |   NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                            ;

CGRect  b1  =   [text boundingRectWithSize:targetSize options:(OPTS) context:nil];
```

This usually works well, but sometimes it shows incorrect result sometimes. Result size for same attributed-text object is about 10pt smaller than it actually rendered with `UITextView`, and I cannot choose correct size for the text-view.

Same code works well with simulators, but broke in actual device. Why this happens and what can I do to avoid this?

Test environment:

- iPod 5th generation
- iOS 7.1.2
- Japanese language mode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I built `NSAttributedString` with no attributes. Not even with `NSFontAttributeName` field. In this case, according to manual, system will choose predefined default font -- "Helvetica, 12pt".

But it seems the OS is choosing some different (which is wrong) sized font for the method in the environment. Maybe because of Japanese language mode. Anyway, `UITextView` rendering routine uses another font, and as a result, measured size becomes different with rendered size.

To avoid this, **just set a font explicitly for EVERY characters** in the attributed-string.

After specifying font for all characters explicitly, I confirmed that all the devices I have and simulators in Xcode 6 are working correctly. I believe there can be more odd cases if I don't set some metric-related attributes. Then I recommend to set all the metric attributes always.

I am not sure what will happen in other environment, but my case was solved with this. I hope this helps.

---

**Update**

I same issue occurs again even after applying this solution. This solution does not provide correct patch. Anyway this problem never appear on iOS 8.0, and I suspect this as a bug in the system framework.